# How can handle request before they come into the API action in ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-boilerplate

In [ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate](http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/) API Controllers generating from [Application Services dynamically](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API). For example I need to throw an exception before request go into the action/method. How handle request? Thanks!

```
public class UserAppService : PlatformAppServiceBase, IUserAppService
{
    private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;

    public UserAppService(IRepository<User, long> userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    // handle request before request executes this action
    public async Task<ListResultOutput<UserDto>> GetUsers()
    {           
        var users = await _userRepository.GetAllListAsync();
        return new ListResultOutput<UserDto>(users.MapTo<List<UserDto>>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have an http module that just fires your validation logic and raises exceptions eariler in the pipeline than the mvc handler runs.

Comment: I try with validation, but if no authorized user, the request just rejected before handling. I look at the sources of Boilerplate, but theirs authorization handler is internal class, so I can't change or override it.